# Backbone's model isValid method with ReactJS view

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs

Dear stackoverflowers.

I faced with interesting technical problem.

At our web application we use [ReactJS with Backbone](https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component). Some one can say this is crappy but the team like this aproach and we use it successfully.

Any way the question is **how can I use backbone's isValid() function in my view** ?

```
saveBtnIsEnabled: function () {
   //@TODO. Here is a problem....
   //... I wana my button be enabled only if my model is valid.  
   return this.props.model.isValid();       
},
```

As for now I can not do that because my

- render function calls isValid() that check and change model
- because model has changed React calls render function
- render function calls isValid() that check and change model
- because model has changed React calls render function...

so I have a recursion.

For now I have all my validation rules at my models.

Here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/alexeiberkov/2wh2q7wb/7/).

Answer (score 0):

When we call isValid() method it change model (it updates `validationError` field of model) so Virtual DOM detect changes and re-render component.

Instead of calling isValid() I change it to call validate() function of model directly. So in my view instead of

```
saveBtnIsEnabled: function () {
     return this.props.model.isValid();
},
```

use

```
saveBtnIsEnabled: function () {
   var model = this.props.model;
   var attributes = model.attributes;
   var validationResult = model.validate(attributes);
   var isValid = typeof validationResult === 'undefined';
   return isValid;
},
```

here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/alexeiberkov/2wh2q7wb/22/).